# React Router not rendering component passed to route when wrapped in another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am using typescript, React and ReactRouter in my Application.

I want to implement an AdminRoute component that only renders when the user has a certain authorization level, and does a redirect (or shows an "access denied" message) otherwise. If I directly implement the logic in my App component, everything works.

But if I create the AdminRoute component and use it in App, it is first not rendered at all (when redirecting using a Link element). 
But after refreshing the page, it is always rendered, regardless of the current URL, below the component of the current route.

### My Code:

App Component:

```
const App: React.SFC<{}>  = (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
       <>
         <Route render={props => <Header {...props} />} />
         <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />{' '}
         <Route exact path="/login" render={prop=>this.loginRedirect(props)}/>
         <Route exact path="/register" render={props => <Register {...props} />} />
         <Route exact path="/user" component={UserCard} />


         <AdminRoute exact path="/adminSettings" component={RestrictedSettings} />

         {/*<Route 
              exact path="/adminSettings" 
              render={props => store.user && 
                store.isAuthorized(UserRoles.Admin) 
                  ? <RestrictedSettings /> 
                  : <h2>Access denied</h2>
              }
            />
         */}

      </>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
```

The commented out code is working, but the AdminRoute is not.

AdminRoute looks like this:

```
const AdminRoute: React.SFC<RouteProps> = 
  ({ component: Component, ...other }) => {
    console.log('accessing protected route');

    return (
      <Route
        {...other}
        render={props =>
          store.user && store.isAuthorized(accessLevel) 
            ? <Component {...props} /> 
            : <h2>Access denied</h2>
        }
      />
    );
});
```

I would expect both, the inline implementation and the functional component, to work exactly the same.

What is the difference? Did I forget to pass a property? Is the typescript compilation at fault?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the router renders all routes that match instead for only one. You should try and use the Switch component, so that it only renders the first one which matches:

```
import {Switch} from "react-router-dom"

const App: React.SFC<{}>  = (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
         <Route render={props => <Header {...props} />} />
         <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />{' '}
         <Route exact path="/login" render={prop=>this.loginRedirect(props)}/>
         <Route exact path="/register" render={props => <Register {...props} />} />
         <Route exact path="/user" component={UserCard} />


         <AdminRoute exact path="/adminSettings" component={RestrictedSettings} />

         {/*<Route 
              exact path="/adminSettings" 
              render={props => store.user && 
                store.isAuthorized(UserRoles.Admin) 
                  ? <RestrictedSettings /> 
                  : <h2>Access denied</h2>
              }
            />
         */}

      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
```

Read more here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components

Comment: Awesome! This works. Thanks a bunch! Im going to read your linked article now, but could you explain why it did work when I was using the commented code instead of the component?